# Pandas DataFrame. Indexing usando .loc()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.7, jupyter

En el ejercicio que muestro a continuación, intento, en primer lugar leer todas las filas de dos columnas especificadas. La sentencia lo resuelve correctamente.
En segundo lugar intento leer solamente las primeras cinco filas de dos columnas especificadas. Me devuelve el error que menciono en el título.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data
data = data.get_data_yahoo('AAPL', '2021-01-01', '2021-06-01')

print(data.loc[:, ['Close', 'Open']])

print(data.loc[:4, ['Close', 'Open']])

TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on DatetimeIndex with these indexers [4] of type int
```

¿Cuál es la causa?.

Comment: no debería de ser `iloc`?  :/

Comment: Con iloc me devuelve: IndexError: .iloc requires numeric indexers, got ['Close' 'Open']

Comment: pásale las columnas como índices

Comment: ¿Por qué esta sentencia sí funciona  print(data.loc[:, ['Close', 'Open']]) y esta otra no? print(data.loc[:4, ['Close', 'Open']])

Comment: por que `loc` trabaja con los nombres de las filas o columnas, y `iloc` trabaja con los índices de las filas o columnas :)

Comment: Las dos sentencias que he indicado en el comentario anterior invocan a .loc. ¿Por qué la primera devuelve el resultado correctamente (todas las filas de las columnas "Close" y "Open", mientras que la segunda da error?.

Comment: ya te lo he dicho, por que `loc` se usa con el nombre de las filas o columnas y no con los índices, podría escribir una respuesta basada en el funcionamiento de `iloc` y `loc` pero también tendría que proponer una solución a tu problema, el cual no he podido recrear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy por partes

### Diferencia entre `loc` e `iloc`

El método `.loc` busca tus datos por el nombre de las filas y las columnas, mientras `iloc` busca tus datos por la posición del indice en la que se encuentran las filas y las columnas.

### El error

Cuando estás utilizando `.loc` le estás pasando el nombre de las columnas `['Close', 'Open']` que es lo correcto, pero para el indice estás usando el nombre de indice `4` y te salta el siguiente error:

`TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on DatetimeIndex with these indexers [4]`

Que te quiere decir lo siguiente: "me estás pidiendo que busque la fila con nombre `4`, pero tal fila no existe, porque tus filas tienen nombres de fechas `Datetimeindex`"

### Soluciones

Una vez sabemos esto, las soluciones son dos:

1. Usando `.loc`: utilizando los nombres de tu indice, que en este caso, **son fechas**, es decir tu ejemplo podría quedar así: `data.loc[:'2021-01-03', ['Close', 'Open']]`
2. Usando `.iloc`: en este caso, **no puedes utilizar nombres, porque este método busca por indice**, por tanto debes utilizar indices en los dos, es decir, tanto en las filas como en las columnas. Tu ejemplo podría quedar así:
   `data.iloc[:4, [1, 2]]` (cogemos las columnas 1 y 2)

Comment: Me habia obcecado por que no me di cuenta de que intentaba reproducir una sentencia de otro notebook, basada en un DataFrame cuyo índice es numérico, y en la que por lo tanto 0 y 4 son índices, utiizando un DataFrame cuyos índices son fechas.